# Which libraries I need to create a websocket client in Android

Tags: android, websocket

please give me some references to build the Android websocket client.

Comment: When you used a search engine to look for `android websocket java library`, what did you learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [**elab's github project**](https://github.com/elabs/mobile-websocket-example) which creates a sample application, including the server side code.

Or you can look into a library of [**android-websocket**](https://github.com/koush/android-websockets)s created by koush. It has good amount of documentation.

---

For more information, try out these projects and post more specific questions if you face any problem while implementing.

Good luck

Comment: thanks I am working on it.

Comment: [elab's guide link](http://www.elabs.se/blog/66-using-websockets-in-native-ios-and-android-apps)

Comment: thanks i used java-websocket , its working fine for me